# For-Loop with numpy array too slow

Tags: python, array, numpy

I'm trying to speed up the execution of the following problem:

I have two functions which are used together.

Here are the functions explained:

The first function simulates `N` coin flips and returns an array of strings with the results:

```
def throw_a_coin(N):
    return np.random.choice(['H','T'], size=N)
```

The second function takes in `number_of_samples, sample_size`
and returns `sample_probs`.
The function simulates `number_of_samples` runs of `sample_size` coin flips and stores the result of `num_heads / sample size` in `sample_probs` for each run.

Here is the code:

```
def make_throws(number_of_samples, sample_size):
    sample_probs = np.zeros(number_of_samples)
    for i in range(number_of_samples):
        num_heads = sum(throw_a_coin(sample_size) == "H")
        sample_probs[i] = float(num_heads) / sample_size
    return sample_probs
```

Now I want to simulate multiple runs with different sample_sizes and 200 runs for each sample size. So `sample_size = 1` I would do 200 runs of 1 coin flip, for `sample_size = 10` I would do 200 runs of 10 coin flips and so on.

Here is the code that takes so long:

```
mean_of_sample_means = np.zeros(len(sample_sizes))
std_dev_of_sample_means = np.zeros(len(sample_sizes))

for i in range(len(sample_sizes)):
    prob = make_throws(200, sample_sizes[i])
    mean_of_sample_means[i] = np.mean(prob)
    std_dev_of_sample_means[i] = np.std(prob)
```

I am pretty sure that this process can be improved by getting rid of the for loops and using array-operations instead. But I just cannot think of how to apply `throw_a_coin` or `make_throws` to an array.

Comment: To the 2 people who voted to close this question: what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code looks very real to me. All required methods are in place so this is fully reviewable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My toy example I build from your snippets:

```
import numpy as np


def throw_a_coin(N):
    return np.random.choice(['H','T'], size=N)


def make_throws(number_of_samples, sample_size):
    sample_probs = np.zeros(number_of_samples)
    for i in range(number_of_samples):
        num_heads = sum(throw_a_coin(sample_size) == "H")
        sample_probs[i] = float(num_heads) / sample_size
    return sample_probs

sample_sizes = [np.random.randint(1, 1e3) for idx in range(500)]

mean_of_sample_means = np.zeros(len(sample_sizes))
std_dev_of_sample_means = np.zeros(len(sample_sizes))

for i in range(len(sample_sizes)):
    prob = make_throws(200, sample_sizes[i])
    mean_of_sample_means[i] = np.mean(prob)
    std_dev_of_sample_means[i] = np.std(prob)
```

cProfile (ordered by cumtime) reveals the problem (runs in 82.359 seconds):

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 133/1    0.003    0.000   82.359   82.359 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.002    0.002   82.359   82.359 fast_flip.py:1(<module>)
   500    0.940    0.002   82.200    0.164 fast_flip.py:8(make_throws)
100000   79.111    0.001   79.111    0.001 {built-in method builtins.sum}
100000    0.058    0.000    2.148    0.000 fast_flip.py:4(throw_a_coin)
100000    1.455    0.000    2.090    0.000 {method 'choice' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
100000    0.207    0.000    0.635    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2456(prod)
100000    0.026    0.000    0.429    0.000 _methods.py:34(_prod)
101500    0.409    0.000    0.409    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
     6    0.000    0.000    0.176    0.029 __init__.py:1(<module>)
```

There is a steep gap after buildins.sum, i.e. you spend most time there. We can use `np.sum` instead (pushing it down to 3.457 seconds):

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 133/1    0.003    0.000    3.457    3.457 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.002    0.002    3.457    3.457 fast_flip.py:1(<module>)
   500    0.905    0.002    3.307    0.007 fast_flip.py:8(make_throws)
100000    0.046    0.000    1.869    0.000 fast_flip.py:4(throw_a_coin)
100000    1.287    0.000    1.823    0.000 {method 'choice' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
201500    0.702    0.000    0.702    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
100000    0.172    0.000    0.536    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2456(prod)
100000    0.136    0.000    0.532    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1778(sum)
100000    0.023    0.000    0.378    0.000 _methods.py:31(_sum)
100000    0.021    0.000    0.364    0.000 _methods.py:34(_prod)
     6    0.000    0.000    0.178    0.030 __init__.py:1(<module>)
```

further we can replace the strings `"H"` and `"T"` with a Boolean and stay in numpy for longer (down to 1.633 seconds):

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 133/1    0.003    0.000    1.633    1.633 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.001    0.001    1.633    1.633 fast_flip.py:1(<module>)
   500    0.101    0.000    1.485    0.003 fast_flip.py:11(make_throws)
100000    0.169    0.000    0.893    0.000 fast_flip.py:4(throw_a_coin)
100000    0.724    0.000    0.724    0.000 {method 'uniform' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
100000    0.122    0.000    0.491    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1778(sum)
100000    0.024    0.000    0.354    0.000 _methods.py:31(_sum)
101500    0.334    0.000    0.334    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
     6    0.000    0.000    0.178    0.030 __init__.py:1(<module>)
```

next we can get rid of `throw_a_coin` and instead sample a `numer_of_samples x sample_size` array of uniformly distributed random numbers and threshold them. This also allows us to vectorize the for loop and stay in numpy even longer (0.786 seconds):

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 133/1    0.003    0.000    0.786    0.786 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.003    0.003    0.786    0.786 fast_flip.py:1(<module>)
   500    0.053    0.000    0.634    0.001 fast_flip.py:4(make_throws)
   500    0.526    0.001    0.526    0.001 {method 'uniform' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
     6    0.000    0.000    0.179    0.030 __init__.py:1(<module>)
```

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np


def make_throws(number_of_samples, sample_size):
    # True == Heads
    throws = np.random.uniform(size=(number_of_samples, sample_size)) > 0.5
    sample_probs = np.sum(throws, axis=1) / sample_size
    return sample_probs

sample_sizes = [np.random.randint(1, 1e3) for idx in range(500)]

mean_of_sample_means = np.zeros(len(sample_sizes))
std_dev_of_sample_means = np.zeros(len(sample_sizes))

for i in range(len(sample_sizes)):
    prob = make_throws(200, sample_sizes[i])
    mean_of_sample_means[i] = np.mean(prob)
    std_dev_of_sample_means[i] = np.std(prob)
```

At this point we could start to tackle the `for` loop, but it would start to get very micro optimized. One might consider aggregating the results in prob and then using `np.mean(prob, axis=1)` and `np.std(prob, axis=1)` outside the loop, but that only nets like `20ms` so it's more of a personal preference thing.

Comment: Wow, very detailed and very helpful! I didn't know I can see how long each single operation takes! Thank you:)

Comment: @DavidP Yes, that's what profilers are for. They exist in every major language so this is not a Python specific thing. There is also [LineProfiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) which allows you to nicely view runtime per line for specific functions.

Comment: I will save this comment in my brain! I didn't know about the profilers and they will help me for sure in the future, thanks a lot!